# Spark StackOverFlowError with distinct() and join operation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, stack-overflow

I'm performing the following operations:

```java
DataSet<Row> df1 = spark.read().format(AVRO_MODE).load(path1);

DataSet<Row> distinctDf1 = df1.distinct()

DataSet<Row> df2 =  spark.read().format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(path2);

DataSet<Row> joinOutput = distinctDf1.join(df2,getColumnStrings(columnList), "leftanti");

joinOutput.repartition(numPartitions, Column.col1).write().format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save(outputPath);
```

When I run the above, I get the following error

```
18/10/26 02:35:19 [Driver]: ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.get(TreeNode.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.<init>(TreeNode.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.<init>(Expression.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.LeafExpression.<init>(Expression.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BoundReference.<init>(BoundAttribute.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$4.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$4.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:152)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Stream.scala:418)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Stream.scala:418)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1233)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1223)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.drop(Stream.scala:858)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.drop(Stream.scala:202)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:64)
```

Any suggestions on why the above error is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show sample data? And contents of Column List? Non common columns?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667368/java-spark-stack-overflow-error-on-groupby